# How do I generate 8 bit (pseudo) random numbers so that I exclude certain known numbers?

Tags: c++, random

I want to generate eight bit (uint8_t) random numbers so that I exclude a set of well known numbers which have already been specified. Basically numbers from 0x00 - 0xFF but I have certain numbers within that range that I do not want to appear.

I am thinking of just populating a vector with the numbers allowed and pick a (pseudo) random index and use that one.

I suspect their may be serious short comings with this so looking for leads/advice. The solution need not be rocket science grade but just simple enough to "appear" random :)

EDIT: I do not want to use external libraries like boost as I am working on ARM embedded solution

EDIT: I do not have support for C++11

Comment: Your solution sounds good to me. Go for it. (Not sure if this should be an answer or comment, but there's really nothing to add; selecting random elements from an array happens all the time...)

Comment: +1 It's a common way to pick random numbers with forbidden values.

Comment: If your list of forbidden numbers doesn't change at runtime, and if 256 bytes is not a lot of memory for you, then I would say yours is the best solution.

Comment: @TonyK - yes it doesn't change and it is 256 bytes memory is tolerable memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    int exclude [] = {4,6,2,1};
    // Test Values for Exclude
    std::sort(exclude, exclude + 4);

    int test = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; ++i)
    {
        // While we haven't gotten a valid val.
        while ( std::binary_search(exclude, exclude + 4, test = (rand() % 256))); 
        std::cout << test << std::endl; // Print matched value
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I think this will work a little bit faster than @IceCoder's solution.

Comment: Yep, really faster with bigger `exclude` arrays too. Since he's going to work on a small range of numbers I also added a new algo which performs only 1 check per number.

Comment: oh! Event better. ta. Will try this and my own suggestion

Comment: Got the error: `algorithm: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 2):

```
unsigned char unwanted[] = {1, 2, 3};
int unwanted_len = 3;
bool found;

do
{
  unsigned char val = static_cast<unsigned char>(rand() % 0xff);
  found = true;

  for(int i = 0; i < unwanted_len; i++)
   if(unwanted[i] == val)
    found = false;
} while(!found);
```

Place this in a function and you're done. You have to include `cstdlib` in order for this to work.

EDIT:

Other possibility (since you are working on a restricted range):

```
bool nums[256];

void init_r()
{
 for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
  nums[i] = true;
}

void get_rnd()
{
 int n;
 do
 {
  n = rand() % 256;
 } while(nums[n] == false);
 return n;
}
```

You can disable any number you want by acting on the `nums` array.

Comment: What's the expected runtime? :-)

Comment: This won't have a very happy statistical distribution.

Comment: I's a slow algorithm, but as he asked simple code, what would be simpler? In addition, as the range of acceptable results is just 256, big unwanted arrays would make it unusable. I'm adding a new algo right now..

Comment: I like this one. It is indeed the small range I am working with and this would suit me fine especially your second edit

Answer (score 0):

A small generic way would be to implement a Generator adapter that filters the Generator. You can then easily implement the predicate in whatever way you want. Here I use a `vector` but a `set` could do fine as well and might provider better performance.

The random generator is provided by the `TR1` and `C++11` random facilities.

```
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <cstdint>
#include <functional>

template<typename Generator, typename Predicate>
struct filtered_generator {
  Generator g;
  Predicate p;

  auto operator()() -> decltype(g()) {
    auto tmp  = g();
    if(p(tmp))
      return tmp;
    else
      return (*this)();
  }
};

template<typename G, typename P>
filtered_generator<G, P> make_filter(const G& g, const P& p) {
  return filtered_generator<G, P>{g, p};
}

int main()
{
  std::mt19937 eng;
  eng.seed(23);
  std::uniform_int_distribution<std::uint8_t> dist(1, 10);
  auto rnd = std::bind(dist, eng);

  {
    // using a vector
    std::vector<uint8_t> forbidden = {1, 2, 3};
    auto g = make_filter(rnd, [&forbidden](std::uint8_t t) {
     return std::find(forbidden.begin(), forbidden.end(), t) == forbidden.end();
    });

    for(int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
    {
      std::cout << static_cast<int>(g()) << std::endl;
    }
  }

  // using a set
  std::set<std::uint8_t> forbidden = {1, 2, 3};
  auto g = make_filter(rnd, [&forbidden](std::uint8_t t) {
   return forbidden.count(t) == 0;
  });

 for(int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
 {
   std::cout << static_cast<int>(g()) << std::endl;
 }
}
```

A C++03 adaption should be easily possible when the generator provides
a `result_type` typedef to remove the dependency on `decltype` and the
lambdas would have to go into functors.